# How to connect SQL Server through DSN in PHP Apache ? (It's not working when Apache Service is On)

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, odbc, dsn

Actually I have try to connect SQL server by using sqlsrv_connect and using the DSN (Data Source Name) without Apache service then the both are perfectly working.

The problem is when I turn on the apache service then php cannot connect to the sql server using odbc DSN (Working with sqlsrcv_connect).

The condition is I need to turn on the apache with a application running using sql server which using DSN. I working with crystal report thats why really need this method. I have tried using system DSN instead user dsn, its also not working.

[image: Apache Service is on]
!

I wrote code below to test my scenario

```
// Connect to the data source 
$conn=odbc_connect('DSNNAME','DBUSER','DBPASS');
if ($conn){
     echo "Connection established DSN";
}
else {
      echo "Connection using DSN Failed:" . odbc_errormsg();
}

// Connect through server name 

$serverName = "WEBSERVER\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBNAME", "UID"=>"DBUSER", "PWD"=>"DBPASS");
$conn2 = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn2 ) {
     echo "Connection established using server name";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established by using server name";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The Result when Apache service is on.

[image: Apache Service is on]

Comment: But you are getting the message `Connection established using server name` from your Second attempt to connect. So what is the problem, use the approach you used in the second attempt to connect

Comment: The second attempt is using sqlsrv_connect. My question is on first attempt to connect sql server using DSN. Why I need to use dsn method because I working with crystal report which connect through DSN

Comment: Are these the actual parameters you used `odbc_connect('DSNNAME','DBUSER','DBPASS');` or did you change those for security

Comment: Its not actual parameters. Yes for security only. If I untick the apache service then it will work perfectly to connect using dsn. Thats make me confuse.

Comment: I dont suppose you setup the DSN to use port 80 by any chance? Sorry been a while since I did this kind of stuff so my memory is a little fuzzy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ODBC DSN matches the Crystal runtime in terms of 32-bit or 64-bit.